# Laravel route not defined but it clearly is

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I keep getting the following error in Laravel 5.3:

> Route [clients] not defined. (View:
>   /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/project-sytem/resources/views/partials/sidebar.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/project-sytem/resources/views/partials/sidebar.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/project-sytem/resources/views/partials/sidebar.blade.php)

Here is my routes file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'ProjectController@index')->name('projects');
    Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectController@index')->name('projects');
    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');


    Route::get('/clients', 'ClientController@index')->name('clients');
    Route::resource('clients', 'ClientController');

});


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

In my `sidebar.blade.php` I have links to my routes like this:

```
<li>
   <a href="{{ route('projects') }}"><i class="fa fa-archive" aria-hidden="true"></i> Projects</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="{{ route('clients') }}"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>Clients</a>
</li>
```

I don't see where I'm going wrong, my `projects` route works just fine and I've done it the exact same way. Any ideas what's going wrong with my `clients` route?

Comment: Shouldn't you place the overwrites _after_ the resources? So that the resources don't overwrite what you first put.

Comment: @JoelHinz You were right. If you put this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Route::resource` overwrites `@index` route with `clients.index`, that's why you're getting the error.

Remove `clients` route completely and use `clients.index` route name in the view:

```
<a href="{{ route('clients.index') }}">
```

Comment: But will `{{ route('clients.index') }}` go directly to the view? I want it to go to the `index()` method of the `ClientController`

Comment: No, it will go to the `ClientController@index` method.